# Grouping MultiIndex in Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm selecting some data in spark like this:

```
base = spark.sql("""
    SELECT
        ...
        ...
""")
print(base.count())
base.cache()
base=base.toPandas()
base['yyyy_mm_dd'] = pd.to_datetime(base['yyyy_mm_dd'])
base.set_index("yyyy_mm_dd", inplace=True)
```

This gives me a dataframe which looks like this:

```
              id    aggregated_field    aggregated_field2
yyyy_mm_dd
```

I want to group by `yyyy_mm_dd` and `id`, but sum the aggregated fields. This way I can see per day, the total sum of the aggregated fields for every provider. I'll then want to aggregate this to be monthly. This is what I've done:

```
agg = base.groupby(['yyyy_mm_dd', 'id'])[['aggregated_field','aggregated_field2']].sum()
```

My dataframe now looks like this:

```
                  aggregated_field    aggregated_field2
yyyy_mm_dd  id
```

Finally, I try to `resample()` to monthly:

```
agg = agg.resample('M').sum()
```

Then I get this error:

> TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'MultiIndex'

I'm not sure why since I convert my yyyy_mm_dd to a date index earlier.

**Edit:** The output I'm looking for is this:

```
yyyy_mm_dd    id   aggregated_metric    aggregated_metric2
2019-01-01    1    ...                  ...
              2
              3
2019-01-02    1
              2
              3
```

Comment: `agg.groupby('id').resample('M').sum()`?

Comment: or `base.groupby('id').resample('M').sum()`?

Comment: @QuangHoang Neither seem to work. Your first comment gives the same error, while the second results in id field also being summed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you will find this useful:

**Solution 1 (employing pd.Period and its "rightful" displaying of monthly data format)**

```
>>> import pandas as pd

>>> base = \
pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'yyyy_mm_dd': ['2012-01-01','2012-01-01','2012-01-02','2012-01-02','2012-02-01','2012-02-01','2012-02-02','2012-02-02'],
        'id': [1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2],
        'aggregated_field': [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7],
        'aggregated_field2': [100,101,102,103,104,105,106,107]
    }
)

>>> base
   yyyy_mm_dd  id  aggregated_field  aggregated_field2
0  2012-01-01   1                 0                100
1  2012-01-01   2                 1                101
2  2012-01-02   1                 2                102
3  2012-01-02   2                 3                103
4  2012-02-01   1                 4                104
5  2012-02-01   2                 5                105
6  2012-02-02   1                 6                106
7  2012-02-02   2                 7                107

>>> base['yyyy_mm_dd'] = pd.to_datetime(base['yyyy_mm_dd'])
>>> base['yyyy_mm'] = base['yyyy_mm_dd'].dt.to_period('M')
>>> agg = base.groupby(['yyyy_mm', 'id'])[['aggregated_field','aggregated_field2']].sum()

>>> agg
            aggregated_field  aggregated_field2
yyyy_mm id                                     
2012-01 1                  2                202
        2                  4                204
2012-02 1                 10                210
        2                 12                212
```

**Solution 2 (stick to datetime64)**

```
>>> import pandas as pd

>>> base = \
pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'yyyy_mm_dd': ['2012-01-01','2012-01-01','2012-01-02','2012-01-02','2012-02-01','2012-02-01','2012-02-02','2012-02-02'],
        'id': [1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2],
        'aggregated_field': [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7],
        'aggregated_field2': [100,101,102,103,104,105,106,107]
    }
)

>>> base
   yyyy_mm_dd  id  aggregated_field  aggregated_field2
0  2012-01-01   1                 0                100
1  2012-01-01   2                 1                101
2  2012-01-02   1                 2                102
3  2012-01-02   2                 3                103
4  2012-02-01   1                 4                104
5  2012-02-01   2                 5                105
6  2012-02-02   1                 6                106
7  2012-02-02   2                 7                107

>>> base['yyyy_mm_dd'] = pd.to_datetime(base['yyyy_mm_dd'])
>>> base['yyyy_mm_dd_month_start'] = base['yyyy_mm_dd'].values.astype('datetime64[M]')
>>> agg = base.groupby(['yyyy_mm_dd_month_start', 'id'])[['aggregated_field','aggregated_field2']].sum()

>>> agg
                           aggregated_field  aggregated_field2
yyyy_mm_dd_month_start id                                     
2012-01-01             1                  2                202
                       2                  4                204
2012-02-01             1                 10                210
                       2                 12                212
```